# c++ program prints prime number using functions

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I've to write a program that prints prime numbers from 1 to 100 (every 5 numbers on a line) using 2 functions: the first to test the number if it's odd and the second to test it if it's prime

I wrote that code but it didn't work
it only prints the last prime number before 100

thanx ^_^

```
#include "stdafx.h"

bool is_odd(int x)
{
    if (x%2==0)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

bool is_prime(int x)
{
    int j=0;
    if (!(is_odd(x)))
        return false;

    if(is_odd(x))
    {
        for(int i=1;i<=x;i++)
            if (x%i==0)
                j=j+1;

        if (j==2)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}


void main()
{
    int x[100][100];
    int i=1;    

    while (i<=100) 
    {
        for(int j=1;j<=20;j++)
            for(int k=1;k<=5;k++)
                if (is_prime(i))
                    x[j][k]=i;
        i++;
    }
    for(int j=1;j<=20;j++)
    {
        for(int k=1;k<=5;k++)
            cout<<x[j][k]<<' ';
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: -1 because you put no effort in.

Comment: ouch... modulo math to check for oddness? `return (x & 0x1)`? The whole oddness business could be eliminated by simply SKIPPING all even numbers. e.g. i=i+2, instead of i++

Comment: As an aside, your code would be a lot more readable if you indented according to an accepted standard.

Comment: You don't have to store the numbers in a 2-D array, just because you want to print them out 5 in a line.

Comment: Why don't you just print it if it's prime? Forget the `j` and `k` loop, just do `if (is_prime(i)) printf("%d\n", i);`

Comment: This pattern is always stupid: `if (condition) return true; else return false;` It's not safe enough, and it really should be: `if (condition == true) { return condition ? true : false; } else { return condition && false; }`. (This is is sometimes called the "safer bool" idiom.)

Comment: Note that `if (x%2==0) return false; else return true;` can be written much more simply: `return x%2 != 0;`.

Comment: @PeteBecker `return !(x%2);`.

Comment: @MarcB I totally misunderstood what you were saying.

Comment: At least format your code in a readable way. It's was hard to understand your program since it's not clear immediately where your ifs and loops begin and end.

Comment: You can change the looping condition for the `is_prime` function to `i*i<x`

Comment: oh.. it doesn't print 1 and 2 !!!

Comment: Your function allow signed integers.  Do they make sense for signed integers?  I suggest changing them to unsigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such amazing complexity for a simple problem. You don't need arrays to do this, not even multi-dimensional arrays.

```
int main()
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; ++i)
    {
        if (is_prime(i))
        {
            cout << i << ' ';
            ++count;
            if (count == 5)
            {
                cout << endl;
                count = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's printing the last number (97) because during each iteration of your loop on `i`, you're setting all elements of the array `x`, then printing it at the end. So naturally, all you'll get is the last prime number. If you want to print only the primes and still maintain your grid, you should do something like this for your `if (is_prime(i))` clause:

```
if (is_prime(i)) {
    x[numPrimes / 5][numPrimes % 5] = i;
    numPrimes ++;
}
```